# Visual basic 6.0 missing richtextedit component option

Tags: vb6, ide, components

I am running Visual Basic 6.0
never had a problem with it before but today when I tried to add the rich text edit component to a new project, it was not in the list of components. I have googled the problem to no avail. i even went to the trouble of i uninstalling and reinstalling visual studio. still didn't help.

does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What Edition of VS or VB6 do you have?

Answer (score 0):

The file must be installed and registered on your computer before you can use it.

It is called `Microsoft Rich Textbox Control 6.0`. Look for the file `richtx32.ocx`. You may need to use the `browse` button on the `components` dialog if vb cannot find the file.

If the file is missing, it may be included in VB6 service packs at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa718364